# Pycharm gives me errors for other .py files when trying to import openpyxl

Tags: python, import, pycharm, openpyxl

I'm trying to follow a guide on excel spreadsheets, but when importing openpyxl it'll give me errors for .py files I've never interacted with before:

[image: Error messages]

I've created a new project in PyCharm and used Python 3.9's location as base interpreter.

Is there something wrong with my Python installation, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Next time post all text as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i see that you're trying to open a file with this framework, the problem is that u didn't specify the path of the file correctly, when you're just saying

```
workbook = load_workbook(filename="sample.xlsx")
```

python thinks that you're importing the file from the same folder as the script, so the solution is to either get the right path
for the file or move you're file to the same folder as the python script aka you're pycharm project, for more questions ask me in the comment section